# Golang : "Err TLS Handshake failed: tls: server selected unsupported protocol version 301" when trying to connect to sql server (diferent host)

Tags: sql-server, database, go, go-gin

This my code when try to connect sql server:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nBzN.png]

```golang
connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s¡port=%s;databases=%s", server, user, password, port, database)

// if there is an error opening the connection, handle it
if err != nil {
  // simply print the error to the console 
  fmt.Println("Err", err.Error())
}

err.Error()) // returna nit on error

defer db.Close()

results, err := db.query("SELECT employee_id, display_name from `person_tbl`")

if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("Err", err.Error())
}
fmt.Print (results)
```

When i try to connect to **sql server**, i get error message
`"Err TLS Handshake failed: tls: server selected unsupported protocol version 301"`
I have tried changing TLS to **version 1.2** on the server and still getting the same error message. Do I need to reset my TLS again or do I need to add code to my Go-lang code?

Comment: Please don't add text (code, error) as image but instead include the actual text here.

Comment: All supported versions of Microsoft SQL Server support TLS 1.2 connectivity. What specific version of SQL Server are you attempting to connect to (what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`)? If you're using the `go-mssqldb` package you might also wish to read through [Go version 1.18 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 disabled by default client-side (sql server old TLS versions not work) #726](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unsupported protocol version" 301 means an insecure TLS version (1.0), selected by the server. (and 301: permanently redirected)

Make sure the Sql-server you are connecting to supports a recent TLS version (like a [TLS 1.2 for a Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe) for instance).

> I have tried changing TLS to version 1.2 on the server

Double-check this [change was effective](https://support.servicenow.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0761102):

- A) TLS1.0 --> `curl -v -s --tlsv1.0 https://<instance-name> -o /dev/null/ 2>&1`
- B) TLS1.1 --> `curl -v -s --tlsv1.1 https://<instance-name> -o /dev/null/ 2>&1`
- C) TLS1.2 --> `curl -v -s https://<instance-name> -o /dev/null/ 2>&1`

Comment: if my server uses http affect the error? Sorry its my mistake don't describe.

Comment: @TriKurAprilianta'Edo An HTTP URL should not be impacted by TLS issue.

Answer (score 3):

You must update Microsoft sql server to support the last TLS, or less secure, you can disable encrypt on connection string like example below.

```
connectionString: "sqlserver://user@SERVIDOR/SQL2012?database=dbexample&encrypt=disable&connection+timeout=30"
```